# Android Studio Gradle Project Refresh failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I was trying to install Android Studio on a new Notebook and continue with my last project. Somehow this does not work as expected. The old Project directory is not found, obviously.

```
 Gradle 'ReFuelProject' project refresh failed: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject'
 using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
 Project directory 'D:\Cloud\Google Drive\code\workspace\ReFuelProject' does not exist.
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: my guess is the space in the project name...

Comment: the thing is, this directory was on my OLD machine. It does not exist anymore

Comment: Well looks like you need to search for that path in your project files and replace it with the new one...

Comment: I already looked everywhere. Couldn't find a single file where this could be changed. Already deleted everything but the source code but nothin... I'm just gonna make a whole new Project...

Comment: I got the same problem. I was in the middle of coding, when suddenly le wild android studio update appeared. I saved my project and updated the software. When I relaunched and opened my project, this error came out.

Comment: @borislemke the only solution I came up with was creating a whole new Project and copy all your source files there. It's a hassle but seems to work.

Comment: @mike.b93 theres a fix on the Android Developer's page I just found yesterday. It works now.

Comment: @borislemke u got a link or sth for me?

Comment: @mike.b93 I thought you've got the issue sorted out already? Here's the link anyway, look in the "Troubleshooting" section in the very bottom. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: @mike.b93 if that doesn't help, there's a "known issues" link at the end of the text as well. Try visiting that page, it might help..

Comment: @borislemke This Problem is indeed no more but i was just curious about an official statement about this :D Thanks for the link :)